# fatal error C1001: internal error trying to use templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use templates for my class. When I hit the run button, I get the following error:

```
1>path\to\the\project\list.cpp(21): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1443)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>          path\to\the\project\list.cpp(48) : see reference to class template instantiation 'List<T>' being compiled
```

Here is my list.cpp file:

```
template<class T>
class List{
public :
    T * first;
    T * last;
    List<T>::List(){
        first = new T();
        first->makeRef();
        last = first;
    }

    void List<T>::add(T * a){
        last->next = a;
        last = a;
    }

    void List<T>::recPrint(){
        recPrint(1);
    }

    void List<T>::recPrint(int id){
        T * p = first;
        int i=id;
        while(!p){
            p->recPrint(i++);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
};
```

Seems like I have a problem using c plus plus templates. I'm new at this and I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Columbo you mean in the declaration of my methods?

Comment: @Masious: You have definitions, not declarations, there.

Comment: @Masious Nevermind - I didn't have a clear mind when I wrote that comment. Remove `List<T>::` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid. When defining member functions inline, the class name is not repeated. That is, where you have

```
void List<T>::add(T * a){
    last->next = a;
    last = a;
}
```

you want

```
void add(T * a){
    last->next = a;
    last = a;
}
```

Alternately, you can move your member function definitions out of the class definition:

```
template<class T>
class List{
public :
    /* ... */
    void add(T * a);
    /* ... */
};

template <typename T>
void List<T>::add(T * a){
    last->next = a;
    last = a;
}
```

---

That said, you really want to use `std::vector` or `std::list` instead of trying to make your own.